# Find map $f : \mathbb{R}\to {\mathbb{R}}$ such that inverse image $f^{-1}(${$x$}$)$ has two elements for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Find map $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that inverse image $f^{-1}(${$x$}$)$ has two elements for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

---

I'm really struggling to find an example so any hints or examples would be much appreciated.

Comment: What restrictions are on $R$? The statement is not true for a one element set.

Comment: I would start by doing this for the half-open interval $[0,1)$.  This would naturally extend to the whole real line.

Comment: I edited your post to clean up spelling and math notation, but then rolled it back after I became concerned I might be changing the meaning of your post.  Have a look at the edit history to see what I thought might be corrections.

Comment: @Jay what do you mean by restrictions on $R$? $\mathbb {R}$ - set of all real numbers is the domain for the map.

Comment: Hint: Both $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$ have the same cardinality as $\mathbb R.$

Comment: If you're looking for a continuous $f$, there isn't any.

Comment: For reasons unknown to me my computer is ot displaying either the domain or the range of the function as blackboard math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For every $n\in\Bbb Z$, map the interval $[n,n+1)$ to itself twice over, by:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
n+2(x-n)  & \text{if } x<n+\frac12 \\
n+2(x-n-\frac12) & \text{if }x\ge n+\frac12
\end{cases}
$$