# Continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ has two elements.

Tags: real-analysis

I saw a question and there was a comment who said there is not such function, but I was not able to se how, any hint?

[Find map $f : \mathbb{R}\to {\mathbb{R}}$ such that inverse image $f^{-1}(${$x$}$)$ has two elements for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4002212/find-map-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr-such-that-inverse-image-f-1x)

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/677085/42969 or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673609/42969

Comment: Alternatively you can ask "Does there exist a continuous function such that any horizontal line $y=c$ for some constant $c$ intersects exactly two points? Then ask what happens when monoticity changes in the function. What does that imply when the function is continuous?

Comment: Why is this tagged "algebraic-topology"?